# Replace string value with mapped value

Tags: php

I have two tables displaying our judges info. One for English the other for French. The last column shows the judges judging division, M = masters, A = Advanced and so on. Only the the first letter is displayed. My db has only the English so I need to change the value to French equivalent.

The logic is like this:

```
$divStr = $row['JudgingLevel'];
if $divStr = "M" then $div = "E";
elseif $divStr = "A" then $div = "I" 
elseif $divStr = "S" then $div = "N";

echo $div;
```

What is the proper syntax for this?

Comment: please look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $div = strtr($divStr = $row['JudgingLevel'], array(
    'M' => 'E',
    'A' => 'I',
    'S' => 'N',
));
```

^ in one strike!